# How to convert decimal time to normal time

Tags: python, datetime

I have a very silly question... how I can convert this timestring to a normal datetime?

```
20170509.54166667
```

Greetings.

Comment: Not really... I have a workaround... but i think there is a shorter way... maybe I'm only confused. :D the number after the point *24  rounded is exacactly the time...

Comment: Maybe you can turn it into a string and then divide the parts into individual segments? Eg: 20170509.54166667 -> 2017 05 09 5 41 66667.

Comment: I’m still confused what 54166667 is...

Comment: The front is correct... the Time is: 2017-05-09 13:00...

Comment: You can do `datetime.strptime("20170509", "%Y%m%d")` to parse the date.  I'm not sure how the part after the dot is supposed to be interpreted.

Comment: @Samwise I think the dupe linked is inappropriate; the OP obviously has no Unix timestamp (it's yyyymmdd.dayfraction instead). Parse the integer part with strptime and add the fractional part as timedelta.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(20170509.54166667)

# which returns this:
datetime.datetime(1970, 8, 22, 11, 55, 9, 541667)
```